# Saving a value through JavaScript's request method

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I run into an issue when trying to use the request method in javascript where I can't save a value. I'll run a block of code like:

```js
let savedData;

request({
  url: url,
  json: true
}, function (err, resp, body) {
  if (err) {
    return;
  }
  savedData = body.data;
});

console.log(savedData);
```

I know that request doesn't block or something, so I think it's run after the `console.log` or something like that? I just need to know how I can save the desired data for use later in the method.

Comment: Not sure you understand the concept of a Promise in JS. Check out this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise also do some reading on what a JS Promise is and how it works. This should help you understand your issue a little more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code **is working correctly**, you're just neglecting the fact that the callback provided as a second parameter to `request()` is executed asynchronously.

At the time when your `console.log()` is executed, the network request may or may **not** have successfully returned the value yet.

---

#### Further Explanation

[Take a look at the documentation for the `request()` function.](https://github.com/request/request)

It states that the function call takes the following signature,

```
request(options, callback);
```

In JavaScript, a callback performs exactly as the name perscribes; it *calls back* by executing the provided function, after it has done what it first needs to.

This asynchronous behavior is especially prominent in making networking requests, since you wouldn't want your program to freeze and wait for the network request to retrieve or send what you've requested.

---

#### Example

```
function callback() {
   console.log('I finished doing my asynchronous stuff!');
   console.log('Just calling you back as I promised.'); 
}

console.log('Running some asynchronous code!');
request({...options}, callback);

console.log('Hi! I'm being called since I'm the next line of code; and the callback will be called when its ready.');
```

**Output**

> - Running some asynchronous code!
> - Hi! I'm being called since I'm the next line of code; and the callback 
>     will be called when its ready.
> - I finished doing my asynchronous stuff!
> - Just calling you back as I promised.

Answer (score 2):

You'll either need to do the rest of the code in the callback of the request function, or use a promise. Anything outside of that callback is going to execute before saveedData ever shows up.

Comment: So I don't think I can do everything in the callback, it wouldn't be possible to write a .then() in this circumstance, right? I would need to write out a promise?

Comment: To do it this way, you'd have to execute the rest of your code in the callback, which is a totally fine way to do it... the callback itself could even be a function that contains the code that would be following the request function.

Comment: But yes, .then() would work too, but the rest of your code would go in that then() block, you still wouldn't be able to run any code after the request() if you need that data for it to work.

Comment: @zbnrg take a look at my answer for an explanation of splitting the callback into a separate callback. I think its what you're looking for!

Comment: I'm just wondering, because I need the request to be called twice (so I want to save each value in an array, because I then need to take the value of each and add it to a string, then return that to a method once, not twice. So I don't think only using a callback would work here?

Comment: Look into returning a promise from `request()`, and then resolve a single promise using `Promise.all()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all